# Simple SELECT statement to get last Wednesday of any month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have one table which is populated with data every Wednesday. So I need to fetch those data from last Wednesday to recently occurred Wednesday.

**For Example:**  If today is **Thursday** (06/06/2013) then I need to fetch data from **29/05/2013** (i.e Last Wednesday of previous month, May) to **05/06/2013** (Yesterday)

I have tried

`select dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,'GetDate()')/7 * 7 + 2,0)` which gives  **05/06/2013**
`select dateadd(wk,-1,datediff(dd,0,'GetDate()')/7 * 7 + 2)` which gives **29/05/2013**

Here in the code, `dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,'GetDate()')/7 * 7` goes to **1st day of the week** (here in this case it is Monday) and by adding +2 it gives Wednesday's date.

**Problem** The code works fine except for Mondays.

For example: consider **Next Monday** (i.e 10/06/2013),

It gives the result from **05/06/2013** (Yesterday) to **12/06/2013** (Next Wednesday)
Instead  I need  **29/05/2013** (i.e Previous of Last week Wednesday) to **05/06/2013** (Yesterday)

Any Ideas?

Comment: So data is populated every day, but you only care about Wednesdays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @ActualDatePayable DATETIME,@LASTDateMonth DATETIME

SET @ActualDatePayable='02/01/2013'

SET @LASTDateMonth=DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(m,1,@ActualDatePayable))

SET @ActualDatePayable=(select MAX(date) AS LastWednesday from (

select dateadd(day,number,@ActualDatePayable) as date from master..spt_values 
where type='p' and number < DAY(@LASTDateMonth) ) t
where   datename(weekday,date) = 'Wednesday')

SELECT @ActualDatePayable
```

Comment: Comma missing:   
select dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, CAST('20130520' AS DATETIME)-2)/7 * 7, + 2.0)

Comment: @Gordon Linoff : Can you tell me the logic behind this query as i get confused of what is going on in the background